# AngularJs testing watchers with $scope variables bound

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-mocha

How can we test $watchers when they are linked to other $scope variables.

```
$scope.value = 0;
$scope.$watch("value", function(newValue, oldValue) {
     $scope.varOld = oldValue;
});
```

I have the above piece of code, how can i test this piece of code?

```
it('test using $digest', function() {
    $scope.value = 0;
    $scope.$digest();

    $scope.value = 1;
    $scope.$digest();

    expect($scope.varOld).toEqual(0);
});
```

I am not sure whether the above tests makes any sense, can anyone help me out on how to test it.

Comment: doen't sound invalid test case at all, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18841293/2435473) would help you

Comment: Why do you ask if the code will work instead of trying it and telling us what is wrong (if anything at all)?.